# Definition of Cohomology, based on coefficient of chain group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

For the usual case where the chain group $\Delta_i(X)$ is free abelian ($\mathbb{Z}$-module)  with basis the $i$-simplices of $X$, the definition of the cochain group is $$\Delta^i(X;G)=Hom_\mathbb{Z}(\Delta_i(X),G)$$, where $Hom_\mathbb{Z}$ refers to abelian group ($\mathbb{Z}$-module) homomorphisms.

Q) My question is what happens if $\Delta_i(X; R)$ is free $R$-module instead, and $G$ is an $R$-module? Do we keep the original definition considering that $R$-modules are also abelian groups, or do we consider $R$-module homomorphisms instead, i.e.
$$\Delta^i(X;G)=Hom_R(\Delta_i(X; R),G)\quad(?)$$

Thanks a lot.

(Btw, are there any references that write about this case?)

Comment: I don't understand the question. $\Delta_i(X)$ is always just a free abelian group.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan How about for the generalization where coefficients are taken to be a in a ring instead of integers? (something like this: https://www.math.unl.edu/~mbrittenham2/classwk/872s07/lecnotes/slides.from.class/cls28--coefficients.pdf)
Perhaps to be more clear we can call it $\Delta_i(X; R)$ instead of $\Delta_i(X)$.

Comment: I mean, you can write down whatever definitions you want. If you make $G$ an $R$-module and require $R$-module maps you will just get back cohomology with coefficients in $G$ in the usual sense, by the tensor-hom adjunction.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see. Thanks. I will look into tensor-hom adjunction.